# Restart animation of previous activity when onBackPressed()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, android-gridview

I have a `GridView` with an animation. When we launch the `activity` the `animation` works, from there if we go to another activity, I need the animation to restart again as the same way as when it was launched. Now when the Back button is pressed, it goes to the previous activity but there is no animation for the aforementioned `GridView`. Here is the code:

```
CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(Grids.this, web, imageId);
grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
grid.setAdapter(adapter);
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.grid_item_anim);
controller = new GridLayoutAnimationController(animation, .2f, .2f);
grid.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
```

Comment: Do this in `onResume()` of the activity.

Answer (score 2):

Go through this link [ActivityLifeCycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

It simply because i'm assuming you wrote your code on onCreate(); when you start activity it calls onCreate() only one time when you switch your activity and come back, your state is changed to onResume() so your code of animation stop working.

you need to write your code in `onResume()` Method which call when you launch activity and also whenever you come back to your activity.

When the Activity **first time** loads the events are called as below:

```
onCreate()
onStart()
onResume()
```

When **switch** the activity

```
onPause()
```

When **back to** activity

```
onResume()
```

**Note:** One thing to be aware of is that onResume() gets called also when a configuration change happens. Putting the code in onResume() will cause the animation tobe played again when you rotate the device.
You might want to avoid this or not depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I assume that you put your code above into the `onCreate()` method of your activity. Try putting it into `onResume()` instead, which is called everytime an activity is resumed *(navigated back to, in your case)*, as opposed to `onCreate()`.